# Extract the hour part from the time and return it as an integer with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, extract, datetime-conversion

I need to extract the hour part from a time column that represents time in the format of:"00:00:00" (hour:minutes:seconds), and return it as an `integer` with `PANDAS`.

For example:
if my `time` value is `00:12:06` I need to get the hour as an integer i.e., `0`

(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if the time column has a string format or a datetime format.

If it is a string, you can :

```
import pandas as pd
df['time'] = ["00:05:12"]
df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda s: int(s.split(':')[0]))
```

If it is a datetime object :

```
from datetime import time
df['time2'] = [time(hour=00, minute=50, second=3)]
df['hour2'] = df['time2'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dt.hour` after converting `time` to `datetime` format

```
# Convert to datetime and extract hour:
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour
```

Example:

```
>>> df
       time
0  00:12:06
1  01:12:06

df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour

>>> df
       time  hour
0  00:12:06     0
1  01:12:06     1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get an integer out of that column, a quick way would be to just grab the string parts that represent the hours and convert it into `int`. Assuming your dataframe has column `df['time']`:

```
df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go. This should give you the logic you need. You basically neeed pandas to build the dataframe and then use apply to extract hour value.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
        {'Id':'01', 'Name': "Donald", 'DOB': '14/06/1946 07:16:00', 'Hour' :None},
        {'Id':'02', 'Name': "Obama", 'DOB': '04/08/1961 15:04:00', 'Hour' :None},
        {'Id':'03', 'Name': "Clinton", 'DOB': '26/10/1947 00:12:06', 'Hour' :None}
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['DOB'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['Hour'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df[['Id', 'Name', 'DOB','Hour']]
```

[image]